# How can I run Ubuntu under Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I am [downloading Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) but I am confused. Should I download the desktop version since I want to keep using Windows as it is.

I just want to run some applications and install some framework using linux. Please let me know what I should do?

Comment: Installing the desktop version of Ubuntu alongside Windows should not damage it in any way. Your other options (as mentioned below) include running it in a virtual machine or directly from CD/DVD/USB without actually installing it at all.

Comment: In any case using [this community documemtation article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) as an installation guide is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu is an operating system, Windows is one too, so there is no Ubuntu “for Windows”.

However you can run Ubuntu in a virtual machine, on Windows, using [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/fr/) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for example. So this will keep your Windows untouched, and Ubuntu will be *running* in a window like an other program.

Here are some tutorials on how to do this:

- http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/02/10/run-windows-in-a-virtual-machine-using-ubuntu-and-virtualbox/
- http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

Comment: There sort of _is_ -- Wubi, a Windows-based installer for Ubuntu. Part of the official distribution.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu is the operating system, like windows. its not a program you run in windows. you can load ubuntu on a dvd or a USB drive and boot from the dvd/usb and run the OS from the dvd without installing, then you can keep windows how it is. they have the instructions here http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download